# how do i find the solution of this trigonometry problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> How do I find the $\angle BCA$?
>
> [image]

I tried to find the formula of the parabola, and I got $y=-0.25(x-4)^2+9$.

Then, with the formula I found the coordinates of point $B$ and $C$ and then the measure between the point $B$ and $C$. Now I am stuck.

Comment: Is $AB$ the tangent to the parabola at $B$? I suggest editing in your calculations that got the coordinates of $B,\,C$.

Comment: If you know the coordinates of $B$ and $C$, then you know the distances $|OB|$ and $|OC|$. You should be able to express the target angle in terms of those lengths. (You should go ahead and put the coordinates of $B$ and $C$ into your question, to help people avoid duplicating your effort.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the equation $y=-0.25(x-4)^2+9$, you can further find the $y$-intercept at $y=5$ by plugging in $x=0$, and the $x$-intercept at $x=10$ with $y=0$. Then,

$$\tan\angle BCA = \frac5{10}$$
Thus, $\angle BCA = \tan^{-1}\frac5{10}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Calculate the slope of the line $BC$, $m$(say). Then $$\angle BCA = \pi - \tan^{-1}(m)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan\,?=\frac{y_B}{x_C}=\frac5{10}.$$